# How to get distinguished names from certificate using private key?

Tags: java, android, certificate

My android app receive (by `aidl`) user certificate and private key. How can I get distinguished name from certificate?

The app that sends certificate and private key can have these names from `Keystore` initialized form `*.pfx` file and using password like this:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
keyStore.load(in, getPassword().toCharArray());
```

And then using alias:

```
Enumeration enumeration = clientKeyStore.aliases();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
     String currentAlias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
     ..
     ..
}
```

I can get all distinguished names

```
 X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(currentAlias);
 Principal subject = c.getSubjectDN();
 String subjectArray[] = subject.toString().split(",");
 for (String s : subjectArray) {
     String[] str = s.trim().split("=");
     String key = str[0];
     String value = str[1];
     Log.d(TAG, key + " - " + value);
 }
```

I cannot pass more information to my app than certificate and private key. How can I reach the same in my app without password using only cert and private key?